# how to get oauth_nonce,oauth_timestamp for mail to api@twiier.com?

Tags: android, twitter, xauth

I want to integrate Xauth to my apps. Any body have idea about how to get oauth_nonce,oauth_timestamp for mail to api@twiier.com?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For xAuth to work with Twitter, you need them to enable your app to work with xAuth.
Before they do so, you need to have it registered for oAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You don't email oauth_nonce,oauth_timestamp to Twitter. You need to register an OAuth application and email them the details listed [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth).